# Flutter layout problems on iOS 16.4 while it works smoothly on Android Emulator

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, user-interface, layout

The layout in our app looks totally messed up on iOS, while on Android there is not a problem at all. I don't get an error code or anything in my console. So I don't really know what to do. If you have any suggestions, please let me know below. Thanks in advance. I've added some screenshots to make it clearer how messed up the layout is.

[image: A example for the AppBar being messed up]

[image: The Login screen which used to look totally fine]

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.1, on macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-x64, locale en-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.10.1 on channel stable at /Users/tristanwieser/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision d3d8effc68 (3 days ago), 2023-05-16 17:59:05 -0700
    • Engine revision b4fb11214d
    • Dart version 3.0.1
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tristanwieser/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone X (mobile) • 6AFF280C-C6A1-4D45-8206-C23FF9F2D434 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)   • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.3.1 22E772610a darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.126

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  Test() {}

  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('So weird'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:actify_app/backend/appUser.dart';
import 'package:actify_app/frontend/homeScreen/eventHomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:actify_app/frontend/signUp/InterestsScreen.dart';
import 'package:actify_app/frontend/SharedScreenFeatures.dart';
import 'package:actify_app/frontend/signUp/EmailSentScreen.dart';
import 'package:actify_app/frontend/signUp/PersonalInfoScreen.dart';
import 'package:actify_app/frontend/signUp/SignUpScreen.dart';
import 'package:actify_app/frontend/signUp/SportsScreen.dart';
import 'package:actify_app/main.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:actify_app/frontend/constants.dart';


class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {

  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Widget _buildForgotPasswordBtn() {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.95,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: () => print('Forgot Password Button Pressed'),
        child: Text(
          'Passwort vergessen?',
          style: kLabelStyle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


 Widget _buildLoginBtn() {
    bool success;
    int register_state;
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
      width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
          elevation: 5.0,
        ),
        onPressed: () async =>
        {
          print('Login Button Pressed'),
          success = await eventHandler.signIn(
              emailController.text, passwordController.text),
          register_state = await getRegisterState(),
          if(success){
            if(register_state == 4){
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SportsScreen(AppUser.fromCurrentUser()))
              )
            }
            else if(register_state == 3){
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InterestsScreen(AppUser.fromCurrentUser()))
              )
            }
            else if(register_state == 2){
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PersonalInfoScreen())
              )
            }
            else if(register_state == 1){
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EmailSentScreen())
              )
            }
            else{
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EventHomeScreen())
                )
              }
          }else{
            SharedScreenFeatures.showAlert(context, 'Für die angegebene Email-Adresse existiert kein Account oder das Passwort ist nicht korrekt')
          },
        },
        //padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        /*shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        ),
        color: Colors.orange.shade300,*/
        child: Text(
          'EINLOGGEN',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF009688),
            letterSpacing: 1.5,
            fontSize: 18.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSocialBtn(Function onTap, AssetImage logo) {
    return GestureDetector(
      //onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        height: 60.0,
        width: 60.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black26,
              offset: Offset(0, 2),
              blurRadius: 6.0,
            ),
          ],
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: logo,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget _buildSignupBtn() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => {
        print("sing in here pressed"),
        Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpScreen())
        )},
    child: RichText(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Du hast noch keinen Account? ',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Hier registrieren',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Color(0xFF00B8A6),
                      Color(0xFF00AA9D),
                      Color(0xFF009C8C),
                      Color(0xFF009689),
                    ],
                    stops: [0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9],
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child:
                  SingleChildScrollView(

                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/logos/logo white.png'),),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                        ),
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Anmelden',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                          fontSize: 30.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05),
                      SharedScreenFeatures.buildEmailTF(emailController, context),
                      SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03),
                      SharedScreenFeatures.buildPasswordTF(passwordController, false, false, context),
                      _buildForgotPasswordBtn(),
                      SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03),
                      _buildLoginBtn(),
                      SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01),
                      _buildSignupBtn(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  //0:everything ok
  //1:email not yet verified
  //2:no first name/ last name
  Future<int> getRegisterState() async {
    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    int userState = 0;

    if (user!= null && !user.emailVerified) {
      userState =  1;
    }
    else{
      CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
      QuerySnapshot query = await users.where(
          'userID', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get();

      query.docs.forEach((doc) {
        if (doc['firstName'] == "") {
          userState = 2;
        }
        else if (doc['sports'].length == 0){
          userState = 4;
        }
      });
    }
    return userState;
  }
}
```